# Binary Search Tree display not showing what I expect

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have been working on displaying the BST in tree version like this: (I dont care about the '/' or '\'.

```
         ___11___
        /        \
       3         15
     /    \      /  \
    1      7    13   19
     \    / \       /
      2  5   9    17
            /
           8
```

I have been getting like this:

To build a BST enter positive integer values, followed by -1

```
5 2 1 4 7 9 11 -1

           11
       9
    7
5
       4
    2
       1

Done


void displayTree(Node *pRoot, int level)
{
    if(pRoot != NULL)
    {
        displayTree(pRoot->pRight, level + 4);
        if (level > 0)
        {
            cout << setw(level) << "    ";
        }
        cout << pRoot->data << endl;
        displayTree(pRoot->pLeft, level + 4);
    }
}
```

so what have I done wrong? I thought my code was pretty straightforward?

Comment: I can't imagine how you'd expect that code to produce the first picture and not the second. It basically just prints each value on a separate line with a number of spaces corresponding to the recursion depth.

Comment: You'll need to do it breadth-first, not depth-first, and you'll need two passes - the first to figure out the tree width so in the second you know where to print the first element.